# Poisson Process with a Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I really couldn't wrap my head around this basic concept so I'm looking help for some basic calculations to solidfy my understanding:

Suppose we have $T\in (0,\infty)$. Say we have $E(T)=\mu$, $Var(T)=\sigma^2$, and it has MGF $M(t)$. $T$ is independent of the Poisson process $\{N(t),t>0\}$ with rate parameter $\lambda$. Consider the random variable $N(T)$. Then how do I find the following terms in terms of $\mu$, $\sigma^2$, and $M(t)$?

1. $E[N(T)]$
2. $Var[N(T)]$
3. $Cov[N(T),T]$
4. $P(N(T)>0)$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know how $E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]$?

Comment: @saz Not a iota of (levy-processes) in here.

Comment: @Did Poisson processes are Lévy processes. And this type of exercise is not that uncommon for lectures about Lévy processes, as far as I know.

Comment: @saz Sure, and in (queuing-theory) as well, and in many other contexts...

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$, $Y$ independent random variables, then

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid Y) = \mathbb{E}(f(X,y)) \bigg|_{y=Y}$$

and so by tower property

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y)) = \mathbb{E} \big( \mathbb{E}(f(X,y)) \big|_{y=Y} \big)$$

In our case, $X \hat{=} N$, $Y \hat{=} T$ - they are independent by assumption. So, for example,

$$\mathbb{E}(N(T)) = \mathbb{E} \big( \mathbb{E}(N(t)) \big|_{t=T} \big) = \mathbb{E} \big( \lambda \cdot t \big|_{t=T} \big) = \lambda \cdot \mathbb{E}(T)$$

where we used that $N(t) \sim$ Poi($\lambda \cdot t)$ for the second equality. The other calculations are similarly.